# GPS(osmdroid offline): Execute a block of codes/methods/main activity until the current location of the user is found

Tags: android, gps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

My android application should get the current location first before doing its main function. I used osmdroid gps and i want it to wait then after, it will execute its main purpose. It's offline so it'd take time before it can get the current location that's why adding `Runnable` is not ideal. 

This is the code for locating the current location of the user(gps)

```
    MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(getApplicationContext(), map);
    map.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();
```

Comment: I guess you can use `callback` or `handler`.!

Comment: @AndiGeeky , does callback specifies the number of seconds?

Comment: `callback` si simple interface!! It does not provide number of seconds. For that you need to save time when you start and stop, then count difference!

Comment: @AndiGeeky alright ill check on it and learn it. im going to bump this if i have problems. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Anytime!!